# Move checked item to other tab in same page after click

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a list of messages. When a message is checked and saved, that message should then be moved to the other tab - let's call it saved. I have that functionality working; however, after each save, the last message is overriding the previous. I need to somehow append the messages after each save without manipulating the DOM. I am using Ionic 3. amessages are the messages that have been saved. rmessages are the messages that the user receives.

Typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-messages',
  templateUrl: 'messages.html'
})
export class MessagesPage {
selectedAll: boolean = false;
messages: string = 'messages';
singleChecked: boolean = false;
rmessages: any[] = [
    { text: 'This is a test message.' , selected: false },
    { text: 'This is a second test message.', selected: false },
    { text: 'This is a third test message.', selected: false }
  ];
 amessages: any[] = []; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { 
}


checkAll(){
  console.log(this.messages.length)
  if(this.selectedAll){
    this.selectedAll = true
  }
  else {
    this.selectedAll = false
  }
}

save(){

this.amessages = this.rmessages.filter(function(x) { return x.selected})

this.rmessages.filter(function (x){ 
      return x.selected;}).map(function(y){ 
        return y.text;});
  this.rmessages =  this.rmessages.filter(function (x) { return !x.selected;})

}
```

HTML

```
<ion-content class="checks">

    <div [ngSwitch]="messages">

    <ion-list active *ngSwitchCase="'received'">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>select all</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox (click)="checkAll()" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" ></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let rmessage of rmessages; index as i">
        <ion-label>{{rmessage.text}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [checked]="selectedAll" [(ngModel)]="rmessage.selected" ></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
        <button ion-button full (click)="save()"  style="font-size:1.8rem">save</button>
    </ion-list>

  <ion-list radio-group *ngSwitchCase="'sent'">
    <ion-list-header>Saved Messages</ion-list-header>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let amessage of amessages; index as i" >
        <ion-label>{{amessage.text}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Do you also want remove checked item from `rmessages`?

Comment: I have the functionality of them being removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change save() function to:

```
save(){

   this.amessages.concat( this.rmessages.filter(function(x) { return x.selected}));
   this.rmessages =  this.rmessages.filter(function (x) { return !x.selected;})

}
```

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. Didn't think of concat(). Thanks!!